# How to connect GCP SQL instance by using Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need help for something, I'm new in Bigquery..

I want to see my SQL tables over Bigquery connection at the Data Studio. However I couldn't figure it out how to connect GCP mySQL instance from Bigquery.

I tried to change region/location of my SQL instance.(I think it helped a little) And using this query at the new BigQuery web UI.. but I receive below error.

SELECT *
FROM
  `myinstanceid.my_database_01.TABLE_YS` ys

Error: ((Not found: Project myinstanceid))

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly connect MySQL databases the only [external data sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources) supported are: GCS files, Cloud Bigtable, Google Drive (even directly google spreadsheets).

To run analytics on data inside your MySQL DB you will need to export data into a supported external data source or even better into a BigQuery native table.

Comment: Is there a way to see "live" data over Bigquery? So we can see the data on Google Data Studio more frequently. (Cloud SQL and MySQL connectors only allow 12 hours data freshness.)

Comment: When you drive Data Studio dashboards from BigQuery tables/views the data is "live" I think that the 12 hours limitation is a connector related limitation. If you design a process to dump data from MySQL to Bigquery you can access data as early as the load process finish.